# mean median and maximum product question

Tags: means, median

The mean and the median of nine distinct positive integers is 30. If the nine integers are such that their product is maximum, what is the product of the smallest and the largest integers?

My attempt:

In this problem, we are given that the mean and the median of a set of 9 distinct positive integers is 30. This means that the sum of the numbers is 9 * 30 = 270 and the number in the middle is 30.

This leaves us with 8 other numbers, which we can arrange in increasing (or decreasing) order.

But I am not sure how to continue with this problem, do I need to create some sort of range?

Here are the option of answers:

210

884

891

3422

Comment: Look [here](/https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/KedlayaInequalities.pdf), in page $3$, the technique inside the proof of Theorem $1$, that some call *smoothing*. You can remove the $30$. If the next two numbers above and below $30$ are $28$ and $29$, ignore them too, and so on. Now consider the first pair (to each side of $30$) that you find that are not distance $1$ from the previous $2$. Do, "smoothing", bring them $1$ closer to $30$ and show that the product got larger.

Comment: @NDB The page has been removed

Comment: For the product of any $n$ terms to be maximum, they are best arranged consecutively.
we can safely say the integers are $26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34$. so your answer should be 884

Comment: @Ercanayan How do you know this fact? For the product of any n
 terms to be maximum, they are best arranged consecutively

Comment: @CountDOOKU i used trial error but i remember seeing a proof on mse

Comment: No, I pasted the URL wrong. It should be [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/articles/files/KedlayaInequalities.pdf)